# Facebook callback right after opening the Oauth popup

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the login flow suggested by the [fb documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web);

**Html**

```
<a href="#">Click me to login!</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//USER WANTS TO LOGIN
$("a").click(function() {
  FB.login( checkLoginState(), { scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_likes' });
})

//CALLBACK LISTENER OF WHAT THE USER CHOOSE
function checkLoginState(mode) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

//WHAT TO DO DEPENDING ON WHAT THE USER CHOOSE
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        //LIFE IS GOOD
        alert("Thank you, know my php script will handle the rest");
    } else if(response.status == 'not_authorized') {
        //THE USER DOES NOT AUTHORIZE
        alert("Im sorry, you have to authorize the app in order to proceed");
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I call *FB.login*, the popup opens as it should asking the user to login or authorize my app, BUT, **as soon as the popup opens the *statusChangeCallback* is called** giving me an status. I don't get why the SDK is giving me a callback as soon as it opens, the user needs to "say something" (login, or authorize or not the app) in order to trigger a response. You see, with this flow, as soon as the user clicks the login button the alert *Im sorry, you have to authorize the app in order to proceed* will popup. Also, worst, is the fact that when the user introduce its credentials in the popup and authorize the app, there is no callback...

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checkLoginState` needs to be passed int `FB.login()` as a function.  You are calling it.

your click event binder should look like this:

```
  $("a").click(function() {
      FB.login( checkLoginState, { scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_likes' });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make the below change and try.

```
//USER WANTS TO LOGIN
    $("a").click(function() {
      FB.login( checkLoginState, { scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_likes' });
    })

    //CALLBACK LISTENER OF WHAT THE USER CHOOSE
     var checkLoginState=function() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    //WHAT TO DO DEPENDING ON WHAT THE USER CHOOSE
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //LIFE IS GOOD
            alert("Thank you, know my php script will handle the rest");
        } else if(response.status == 'not_authorized') {
            //THE USER DOES NOT AUTHORIZE
            alert("Im sorry, you have to authorize the app in order to proceed");
        }
    }
```